# accessing cookies in a DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Cookies received by my web API (written in C#) are of the form:

```
Method: GET, RequestUri: 'URI', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler+LazyStreamContent, Headers:
{
  ...
  Cookie: cookie1=0afb1029-be3d-4aba-86a3-5af73a55ce02; cookie2=some.string
  ...
}
```

However in my C# I am forced to deal with that cookie line as a string.

```
public class HandleAuth : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var cookies = request.Headers.GetCookies();

        if (cookies.Count > 0)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> cookieSet = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string userCookie, authCookie;

            try
            {
                cookieSet.Add(cookies[0].ToString().Split(';')[0].Trim().Split('=')[0],
                              cookies[0].ToString().Split(';')[0].Trim().Split('=')[1]);
                cookieSet.Add(cookies[0].ToString().Split(';')[1].Trim().Split('=')[0],
                              cookies[0].ToString().Split(';')[1].Trim().Split('=')[1]);
            }
            catch (...)
            {
            }

            if ( cookieSet.TryGetValue("cookie1", out authCookie) &&
                  cookieSet.TryGetValue("cookie2", out userCookie)
                )
            {
              // do stuff
            }
        }

      // async, etc...

  }
}
```

Which really stinks, and other cookies in that domain mess things up quickly. Is there not a better way to handle cookies in a `DelegatingHandler`? The method provided by [this 6+ year old MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies#example-set-and-retrieve-cookies-in-a-message-handler) doesn't work at all. Lines like

```
sessionId = cookie[SessionIdToken].Value;
```

simply refuse to compile or throw an exception.

What am I missing? Targeting .Net 4.6.1.